# Prevent clicks without Pre-Launch warning about "Multiple clickable items share this location on the screen"

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play, accessibility

In my app, I push/pop fragments on to/off of a stack as the user navigates to various screens. Imagine Fragment A is the bottom layer, Fragment B's UI sits on top of that, Fragment C's UI sits on top of B.

I previously had a problem that when a user would tap on Fragment C's background (i.e. not hitting any particular button or anything) that tap would fall through to Fragment B and hit one of the clickable items there and trigger that action. That was no good, obviously, but was easily fixed by making the background of Fragment C `clickable="true"` then it would consume any taps instead of letting them fall through.

But Fragment C has a ListView and the Google Play Pre-Launch Report is complaining about Accessibility because I have "Multiple clickable items share this location on the screen" (i.e. the ListView is clickable and my background RelativeLayout is also clickable.

How can I prevent clicks from falling through to fragments below without causing Accessibility issues in the Pre-Launch report?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```